# Collection literal of non-contiguous ranges

Tags: groovy

In Groovy, I can easily define contiguous ranges:

```
(1..10)
```

How can I define a collection with non-contiguous ranges in an easily readable format like e.g.

```
(1-3,2,4-10)
```

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or use the spread operator:

```
def custom = [*1..3, 2, *4..10]
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done by flattening a variably typed ArrayList literal with an arbitrary mix of single items and nested contiguous ranges:

```
[1..3,2,4..10].flatten()
```